# Deleting a branch folder in TFS

Tags: tfs

So i just branched from my main project only to realize that i only needed to branch from one project within the main so now in my branch i have all other projects in which i don't need could i safely delete them from the branch?
**OR**
should i delete the whole branch folder using `tf destroy` and create a new branch from the main project which i only need. I tried deleting the whole branch folder but it is not allowing me to delete but i could delete some folders within the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how tightly coupled this code will be to the main project & how many dependencies it has on your other projects. If it's entirely isolated & will not have any dependencies you're better off destroying the errant branch using 'tf destroy' & just branching the project to have a cleaner source tree.

Otherwise I'd actually recommend removing only the completely unrelated projects. Any framework projects you reference in the branched project should remain part of the branch as well just in case you need to change them, it can be done without impacting the main branch.

Comment: how can i delete the branch properly - `destroy the errant branch`

Comment: you should use 'tf destroy'

Comment: Something like this: `C:\tf destroy $/MyTeamProject/Branches/FolderToDelete`

Comment: Yeah, that's the command. Just make sure you don't want to keep anything from this branch since it will be completely removed from the merge history

Comment: not sure if i am missing something but running that i get an error stating that `tf` is not recognized command

Comment: make sure you're running this from the visual studio command prompt and that you're on at least TFS 2008

Answer (score 3):

I just did the exact same thing you described.  My solution was to convert the branch to a normal folder.  Then you can delete the folder and check in the change.